# F# Literal/constant can be composed with strings, but not int?

Tags: f#

Why is this OK:

```
let [<Literal>] hi = "hi"
let [<Literal>] bye = "bye"
let [<Literal>] shortMeeting = hi + bye
```

...but this is not?

```
let [<Literal>] me = 1
let [<Literal>] you = 1
let [<Literal>] we = me + you
```

The third line gives the error:

```
This is not a valid constant expression
```

What's up with that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the spec / docs are a little unclear, but provide hints.

From the spec (for F# 3.0):

> A value that has the Literal attribute is subject to the following
>   restrictions:
>
> It may not be marked mutable or inline. It may not also have the
>   ThreadStaticor ContextStatic attributes. The righthand side expression
>   must be a literal constant expression that is made up of either:
>
> A simple constant expression, with the exception of (), native integer
>   literals, unsigned native integer literals, byte array literals,
>   BigInteger literals, and user-defined numeric literals.
>
> OR
>
> A reference to another literal

This seems to suggest that even the combination of strings isn't allowed.

The documentation states that this changed in F# 3.1:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233193.aspx

> As of F# 3.1, you can use the + sign to combine string literals. You
>   can also use the bitwise or (|||) operator to combine enum flags. For
>   example, the following code is legal in F# 3.1:

Note that integer addition is not on that list

Comment: That's annoying, because it means I have to calculate lots of constant values when translating a C API. Anyway, thanks for clarifying this.